# How do I import a set of libraries in a .pkg file into Xcode 4.6?

Tags: c++, xcode4.6

I am currently taking a few different online programming courses, one of which is the Programming Abstractions Stanford course. They have a set of default libraries that are utilized for the class.

You can download that package here:
http://see.stanford.edu/materials/icspacs106b/cs106libs_for_xcode.zip

I am needing assistance with figuring out how to get this package of libraries into Xcode so that I can utilize them with the programs I write. How can I go about doing that so when I create a new project I can create one that has these libraries ready to go, on top of the standard C++ libraries.

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Edit: I did install the .pkg file, but I do not where it installed. How do I utilize the installed library from within Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad luck. From this page:

[How to install external library in X-Code 4](http://www.techques.com/question/1-9687103/How-to-install-external-library-in-X-Code-4)

> You need to install XCode 3.0 in order to use
>   CS106LibrariesForXcode.pkg library.
>
> XCode 4 have a very different UI and functionality compared to XCode
>   3. So it would be unwise to study XCode 3 only. But if you're going to study C++ using those tutorials you'd probably want to install XCode 3
>   and use it.

---

**Old answer** [Not applicable]

If the package is a pkg file, you actually needs to install it. Double-click on it, follow the steps.

If you have a warning message,

> CS106LibrariesForXcode.pkg” can’t be opened because it is from an
>   unidentified developer.

then right-click (or ctrl+click) and select open. The warning will then have an open option to allow you to open the package.

Once this is done, just write a new program, and include the headers you need.

Comment: I did install the package. It says that it installs correctly, but I have no idea where to find it, import it, utilize it, etc. from within Xcode. How can I go about doing that? Thanks!

Comment: Well, there is nothing more to do. Just write your program (and include the relevant headers).

Comment: I did do that, but it says that the file is not found. Is there a specific project template that I need to choose for writing a C++ program that will contain these libraries?

Comment: I did install the package. What header do you need to include? If you give me the names, I can try on my computer. If they have a doc, please could you provide me the link?

Comment: The name of the headers are "genlib.h" and "simpio.h", but here is a link to the details of the library. http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106b/materials/cppdoc/

Comment: @Jonathan It seems you can't use those libraries with Xcode 4. see my [updated] answer.

Comment: Thank you for getting back! I could imagine why it would only work on Xcode 3.X. It's because this class/resources are rather old. I found an assignment from the current version of the same class, which appears to have an updated version of the library. Is there any way to import the library from the projects this assignment has into Xcode? http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106b/assignments/Assignment1-xcode.zip

Comment: @Jonathan For cs106b, see here: **CS106B libs for use with Xcode 4.x** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735639/cs106b-libs-for-use-with-xcode-4-x